# How to get status code from running service?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, microservices, resttemplate

I have my own microservice with the URL in the network and I have created a REST API for it.

If I launch it locally, it has URL like `http://localhost:8585`.

If I run it f.e. on the development stage , it has microservice URL.

It works fine I can add objects, get objects etc. from my database but I want to create additional check whether my service is running or not.

For example, if my service is running, I can add new Object to database. If not, I can't add and throw some exception.

I tried to do it `HttpStatus statusCode = restTemplate.getForEntity(currentUri, String.class).getStatusCode();`

But I received exception `HttpClientExceptionNotFound: 404 Not Found Request Was Not Matched`

Comment: 'if my service is running' --- it's often called health check, and in springboot there's [Actuator](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/actuator.html)

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
RestResponse response = HttpRestClient.getWithStatusCode("URL", 
 headers).getStatusCode();
```

---

```
public final class HttpRestClient {
/**
 * Issue an HTTP GET and assert the response status code.
 *
 * @param url to GET.
 * @return the body of the response.
 */
   public static RestResponse getWithStatusCode(String url, Map<String, 
    String> customHeaders) throws RestClientException {
    HttpGet get = new HttpGet(url);
    LOG.info("Call url " + url);
    get.addHeader("Accept", "application/json");
    if (customHeaders != null)
        for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : customHeaders.entrySet()) {
            get.addHeader(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
        }
    return methodWithStatusCode(get, -1);
 }
```

}

Comment: I can't find dependency for `HttpRestClient`

Comment: Replace that  with Class Name where you are writing getWithStatusCode() method.